# Understanding MultiSet in Oracle & advantages,importance of it

Tags: oracle

I have seen a lot of answer's using Multiset & AS SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST etc.. and I am not able to understand the logic behind/ how it works out. Please find below example (actually taken from another question). Request you to please explain the workflow/working for understanding multiset. And yes I tried to read the documents related to it.

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Id, Column1, Column2 ) AS
SELECT 1, 'A,B,C', 'H' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'D,E',   'J,K' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'F',     'L,M,N' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT t.id,
       c1.COLUMN_VALUE AS c1,
       c2.COLUMN_VALUE AS c2
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN
       TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( t.Column1, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL )
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( t.Column1, '[^,]+' )
           ) AS SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST
         )
       ) c1
       CROSS JOIN
       TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( t.Column2, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL )
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( t.Column2, '[^,]+' )
           ) AS SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST
         )
       ) c2
```

**Result:**:

```
| ID | C1 | C2 |
|----|----|----|
|  1 |  A |  H |
|  1 |  B |  H |
|  1 |  C |  H |
|  2 |  D |  J |
|  2 |  D |  K |
|  2 |  E |  J |
|  2 |  E |  K |
|  3 |  F |  L |
|  3 |  F |  M |
|  3 |  F |  N |
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle offers three different types of collection, on other languages term "array" is more common.

- Associative array (or index-by table)
- VARRAY (variable-size array)
- Nested table

Have a look at [Collections Types](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS00501) in order to see the differences and where which one can be used.

Start with something simple, e.g.

```
create type number_table_type as table of number;
```

You can use them in several ways, the three `selects` are equivalent. They all select table `emp` and stores `emp_id` values into Nested table `emp_T`.

```
create table emp (
    emp_id number,
    emp_name varchar2(100));

insert into emp values (10, 'Scott');
insert into emp values (20, 'King');
insert into emp values (30, 'Tiger');


declare
   emp_T number_table_type:
begin
   select cast(collect(emp_id) as number_table_type)
   into emp_T
   from emp;

   select emp_id
   bulk collect into emp_T
   from emp;

   SELECT CAST(MULTISET(SELECT emd_id FROM emp) AS number_table_type)
   into emp_T
   FROM dual;

   emp_T := number_table_type(10,20,30);
   
   for i in 1..3 loop
       emp_T.EXTEND;
       emp_T(i) := 10*i;
   end loop;
end;
```

For the opposite way, i.e. transform a Nested table into "normal" table use `TABLE` function:

```
select *
from TABLE(emp_T);
```

Oracle provides [Multiset Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/operators006.htm#SQLRF0032) and [Multiset Conditions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/conditions006.htm#SQLRF52128). They offer function like join two arrays, make values distinct, etc. Many times I see developers writing a `LOOP` in their code where a Mulitset Operator/Condition would do the same stuff with a single command.

Once you are familiar with such basic array you could also try more complex structures. However, according to my feeling such complex structures are quite common in training material and documentation but hardly used in "real life". Oracle strength is to store and manipulate relational data, rather than object oriented data.

`SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST`, et al. are just some [predefined types](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dcicnstnts.htm#i76582). Actually it does not matter whether you use them or create you own types.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you should review such a code from the deepest level and navigate up, in order to figure out what's going on.

This is based on the first row of your table: as you can see, that "regexp" *magic* converts your comma separated values (i.e. column) into rows.

```
SQL> with test as
  2    (select 1, 'A,B,C' column1 from dual)
  3  select regexp_substr(t.column1, '[^,]+', 1, level)
  4  from test t
  5  connect by level <= regexp_count(t.column1, '[^,]+');

REGEXP_SUBSTR(T.COLU
--------------------
A
B
C

SQL>
```

MULTISET creates a "collection" of those values, while CAST "converts" it into a SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST type. It is, as you can see, owned by SYS and acts as if you created your own type (using the CREATE TYPE command) which contains VARCHAR2 values. When types are "simple" as this one, or the one that contains numbers (so you'd use SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST), you can use predefined one instead of creating your own. Therefore, that collection contains A, B and C.

Finally, TABLE function produces a collection of rows that can be queried, just as if it was an "ordinary" table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.